# Regex: match a url but not an email domain

Tags: regex, email, url

I have a very loose regex to match any kind of url inside a string: `[a-z]+[:.].*?(?=\s|$)`
The only problem is that this regex will also match the domain of an email, when instead i want to exclude from the match any email address.

To be precise i do want the following match (matched string in bold)

> test **example.com** test
>
> test emailstring@myemail.com

Any solution i tried just excludes `emailstring` and matches `myemail.com`

Here's a more complete test case https://regex101.com/r/NsxzCM/3/

Comment: Is it really worth it trying to construct a monstrous error-prone regex that will filter out all url's but exclude emails? Wouldn't it be much easier to first find all url-like strings, and then check in the second step that they are not e-mail addresses?

Comment: It's a good point but i need to parse a text and replace the url with markup on the fly. Not sure how to do this in multiple steps. Unless i split the whole text by spaces, replace and then rejoin, but keeping track of which part was an email and which wasn't (so i can parse the url instead) will make it messy

Comment: you can put an except @match before your match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a two-step proposal that uses regex `replace` with lambdas. 
The first regex finds everything that looks like an ordinary URL *or* an email, and the second regex then filters out the strings that look like email addresses:

```js
input = 
  "test\n" +
  "example.com\n" +
  "www.example.com\n" +
  "test sub.example.com test\n" +
  "http://example.com\n" +
  "test http://www.example.com test\n" +
  "http://sub.example.com\n" +
  "https://example.com\n" +
  "https://www.example.com\n" +
  "https://sub.example.com\n" +
  "\n" +
  "test example@example.com <- i don't want to match this\n" +
  "example@example.co.uk    <- i don't want to match this\n" +
  "\n" +
  "git://github.com/user/project-name.git\n" +
  "irc://irc.undernet.org:6667/mIRC jhasbdjkbasd\n";

includeRegex = /(?:[\w/:@-]+\.[\w/:@.-]*)+(?=\s|$)/g ;
excludeRegex = /.*@.*/ ;

result = input.replace(includeRegex, function(s) {
  if (excludeRegex.test(s)) {
    return s; // leave as-is
  } else {
    return "(that's a non-email url: " + s +")";
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I ended up implementing this solution and it worked pretty well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
(:^|[^@\.\w-])([-\w:.]{1,256}\.[\w()]{1,6}\b)
```

helps but i don't know why it matches extra `\` as well

Comment: This regex matches xpto.com but not email@xpto.com. That what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
const URL_INCLUDE_REGEX = /[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/ig;
const URL_EXCLUDE_REGEX = /.*@.*/;
```

The second one is for excluding emails. So the final code will be:

```
const text = "My website is example.com";
// const text = "My email is test@example.com"; <- this will not be matched as there is email, not a url

let result = false;

text.replace(URL_INCLUDE_REGEX, (matchedText) => {
  if(!URL_EXCLUDE_REGEX.test(matchedText)) {
    result = true;
  }
});
return result;
```

where result will be `true` or `false`